# Make a clickable URL substring

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I’m creating an app that receives a message, periodically, from a server. That message is a text string that contains, somewhere, a URL within it. So that might look like:

```
“I’m just a string with this URL “ +<a href="http://www.somewhere.com">Somewhere.com</a>+ “ that I’d like you to visit.”
```

This message appears, as htmlText, inside of TextField and I’d like AIR to let the receiver of this message just tap on the URL substring to launch the browser toward the URL.

I know how to do this the ‘hard way:’ use a  Regex to find the URL, copy the URL substring, assign it to a URLRequest and then navigateToURL( ) when any part of the entire string is tapped.

Is there a neater way to make a substring the target of a TouchEvent or MouseEvent?

Comment: Does the string actually contain those quotes and + symbols? You do know that `TextField`/`htmlText` supports rendering `<a>` tags as links, right?

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. I DID test that idea within Flash and did not get the expected behavior. I'll try a little harder. Thanks.

Comment: By default it will not make links look any different (underline, blue, etc), but it does become a link if the syntax is valid. You can use `StyleSheet` CSS to style links how you want.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I get this now.

Answer (score 1):

Try URL encoding the string that the server sends, then unencode it when Flash adds it to a TextField that has its htmlText property set to true.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001601.html

If you're using PHP you do this with url encode.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

And to unencode this in Flash you use unescape();
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7ff0.html

e.g. Your string wouldn't need any +'s

```
$str = urlencode("I’m just a string with this URL <a href='http://www.somewhere.com'>Somewhere.com</a> that I’d like you to visit.");
```

Also, be careful not to use " inside your string as this will terminate it early. i.e. use single quotation marks to enclose your href url.